# Powers of $2$ and $3$ and primality radius

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

Say a non negative integer $r$ is a primality radius of $n$ if both $n-r$ and $n+r$ are prime.

Are there infinitely many such couples $(n,r)$ of the form $(p^a,q^b)$ with positive $a$ and $b$ and $\{p,q\}=\{2,3\}$?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking if there are infinity many $a,b$ such that $2^a-3^b$ and $2^a+3^b$ are prime?

Comment: Or the other way around, except if you allow a negative integer to be considered as "prime".

Comment: Why? $27=3^3$ admits $4=2^2$ as a primality radius, so that $27$ lies midway between the primes $23$ and $31$, so that $54=2\times 27=23+31$ is an even number which is the sum of two primes so meets the requirements of Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: You're right. Brain spasm on my part. Comment deleted.